# PHPMailer with GMail: SMTP Error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am making use of PHPMailer to send mail through GMail. The code I use is straight from a tutorial and it works perfectly on my laptop. However, testing this on a Windows 2003 Server - it seems to always return an SMPT error:

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP
>   host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could
>   not connect to SMTP host.

Here is the settings I use in PHPMailer:

```
include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // use ssl
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMAIL's SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // SMTP port used by GMAIL server
```

Can I say with confidence that this isn't a port issue, since I am connecting to another server on port 465 and it is sending mail. If not, please explain.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks all for any help

Comment: What happens when you run `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` on the command line?

Comment: On both my laptop and the server, I am able to use telnet i.e. I didn't get any errors, the command window title changed to `Telnet smpt.gmail.com` and it was awaiting more commands. Typing `bye` allowed me to exit. What does this tell you as I have no idea?! Does it mean it isn't a port/firewall issue?

Comment: I also needed `$mail->Username = "myUsername"; // SMTP username` and `$mail->Password = "myPassword"; // SMTP password` to successfully send mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing notice off-hand: Gmail uses TLS. Don't know if having SSL instead of TLS will make much of a difference but SSL is the predecessor to TLS.

I recommend checking out also, its phpmailer customized for using gmail. [PHPGMailer](http://www.thedanglybits.com/2006/10/13/update-send-email-with-php-and-gmail-hosted-for-your-domain/)

Comment: thanks for asking to have a look at that SSL thing. Even though it wasn't the issue, I found out that the problem was with fsockopen - it wanted the openssl extension which wasn't enabled on the server!! :)

Comment: Ah cool, would have said that but the error I remember for not having it enabled looked a bit different.

Comment: Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079061/phpmailer-saying-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Answer (score 2):

To use PHPMailer with gmail, don't use SSL/465 (it's been deprecated since 1998), use TLS/587 as Noctrine suggests, and here's how:

```
include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com"; // GMAIL's SMTP server
$mail->Port = 587; // SMTP port used by GMAIL server
...
```

You should find that works.