# Can't send mail from php using xampp

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, localhost, sendmail.exe

I want to send mail in php from localhost, I had config two files php.in and sendmail.in, but not working for me. I'm using windows 8

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

In sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myaccount@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
force_sender=myaccount@gmail.com
```

and my file php to check send mail

```
mail('myaccount@gmail.com','test subject','test message',"From: username01@gmail.com")
```

but not working, this is my debug file

```
14/06/08 18:57:25 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
14/06/08 18:57:25 ** To: myaccount@gmail.com
14/06/08 18:57:25 ** Subject: test subject
14/06/08 18:57:25 ** From: username01@gmail.com
14/06/08 18:57:25 ** 
14/06/08 18:57:25 ** test message
14/06/08 18:57:25 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
14/06/08 18:57:27 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
14/06/08 18:57:27 ** Connected.
14/06/08 18:57:27 << 220 mx.google.com ESMTP 8sm79651218igr.2 - gsmtp<EOL>
14/06/08 18:57:27 >> EHLO admin<EOL>
14/06/08 18:57:28 << 250-mx.google.com at your service, [1.52.22.18]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250 CHUNKING<EOL>
14/06/08 18:57:28 ** Authenticating as khanghuynh92@gmail.com
14/06/08 18:57:28 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
14/06/08 18:57:28 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
14/06/08 18:57:28 >> QUIT<EOL>
14/06/08 18:57:28 <<  5  1S”O§×ãd´§ÒÞð5U0~K’ˆî8`fwqLÚÙú     ÿ   #     z0‚v0‚^ :ä^nìó0
    *†H†÷
 0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G20
130910075447Z
140910075447Z0h10   UUS10U
California10U
Mountain View10U

Google Inc10Usmtp.gmail.com0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ©0 ÚÖÖ×Ì®TË¥Ÿ.Jå‚ð·›’
QSÙ^ú{pî¯69~0!ã…°vFH;ARDñãRWAé«{Î»?‘CjÏ)öž3s’~´«WšUm› VäVË—e;¾õðÄ7òù’–c¤bœZßæ’%•Ò¨Ýf'v?P>_ˆ,¨ÌihB?’Ÿs2Ç6>á?ßYCI¨|   ±^2òš¿D…Ÿ$X3~˜ð$Øqõÿ®¢VñöÓ [§º«ÇTÕN–æî¾ÞÖmbc0¿™¢²‘öŸ•Ó½'3xÙ‘<Vpú¥õã%ãÂÿy})´†d¶Ô‚µéâ™ÁJ0½[ £‚A0‚=0U%0++0U0‚smtp.gmail.com0h+\0Z0++0†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0++0†http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0UCMe¸ˆÌ×vø:†)Æð&º0Uÿ0 0U#0€JÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0U 00
+Öy00U)0'0% # !†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
    *†H†÷
 ‚  Þ}@µ†¼-
FÅìY§y¼_x¤_ƒYƒDZš§®×a”àbÑyC¤neï}F–<“y"LÞ¢ûsÍ¨‰S3åK “ÿ)HÚD¨ÿB¦ßŠÀçðüà–¿Õ$<qàqTÐYN`íR±n…ùÿÐ™9™'ýå`²;Ög®ºÞÎìopYWV˜låt²ë’äÎ$×ŠD~1Œ"¡¿p0?Joª ó«Gè®¡˜Q9»X.+(¶ÇÓË<ƒ.¹Ëñ"h–(J«>¯m®Ë¶Æh(,WýàÝ`T•îi•å
pN­mé!óc×ÃaÂeüÐza+î‹!Tåö 0‚0‚ì :i0
    *†H†÷
 0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0
130405151555Z
150404151555Z0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#U
14/06/08 18:57:28 << Google Internet Authority G20‚"0<CR>   *†H†÷<CR> ‚ 0‚
‚ œ*w\ØP‘:£‚àØPH¼‰?ñpˆF~àÅñ‰Î!îZþa
·2D‰ tSOU¤Î‚b•îëY_Æá€Ä^”?¼[H8ôS÷$æû‘éÄÏôS
ôJüŸTÞ}¾ ko‡ÀÐP(0@ÚsQlÿ:<§7Ž½Kë}$Þæùü1qû”Õ`ó.J¯BÒËêÄj²ÌSÝK‹ÈaÍ¨>c+„5ie„ÈÅF"øS•¾ã€JÆ*ìº— Ç9™ ðaz•%ŒNRuâ¶íÊüÎ"j³NÏF——~À±Þ{¯E3Ïº>q·Þô%%Â
5‰ûy‰7Å¯Žri £û0ø0U#0€Àz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0UJÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0Uÿ0ÿ 0Uÿ0:U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/gtglobal.crl0=+10/0-+0†!http://gtglobal-ocsp.geotrust.com0U 00
+Öy0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 6×€'­*›8w³# uX»±~ƒBºrÚØŽ6—àð•;7ýBXþ"Èk½8^Ñ;%në^gvF@ÚÈx
í•fÚŽ†o€¡ºV2•†ÜÜjÊŒ[ö¿Ìo…XÃhQÍýÈ÷y=™5ðV£½àYíOD  £ž8zöFÑO¾Ð@üUþ^<ÚV½–Q{oW*Û¢ª–ÜŒtÂ•¾ðn•ÿð<¬²ÌsûèÆðû3³•;ãÂËhXsÛ¨$b;5
©3½x.Lx]P:Ôî Èp8Ü²ùgú‡@]aÀQkƒkÍ:Êá§xüÊÚ”Ð,=~yÈ P $T3q 0‚}0‚æ »æ0
    *†H†÷
 0N10   UUS10U
Equifax1-0+U$Equifax Secure Certificate Authority0
020521040000Z
180821040000Z0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ÚÌc0ýô#V~[ß<l8äq·x‘Ô¼¡ØLø¨C¶éM!ˆÚX/f9)½x‹8è·j~q¤æÄ`¦°ï€ä‰(ž%Öíƒó­¦‘Ç˜ÉB5­˜F’.OÊñ‡CÁ•W-Pï‰-€zW­òî_kÒ ¹ø5ÙÀF£{rÈ‘¿ÉU+ÍÐ—>œ&dÌßÎƒqÊNæÔÕ{©ÍUÞÈìÒ^8Så\OŒ-þP#6üfæËŽ¤9 ·•9‘þ8.ÑšöM>o¯,`9âú6S9Ô^&+Û=¨½2ë(Rqå«3=á8»6„bœyê0ô_À+èqkäù £ð0í0U#0€Hæhù+Ò²•×GØ# O3˜
14/06/08 18:57:28 << ŸÔ0UÀz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0Uÿ0ÿ0Uÿ0:U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/secureca.crl0NU G0E0CU  0;09+-https://www.geotrust.com/resources/repository0
    *†H†÷
  vánNK†0²ÏðÇÇq~fîÂíÔ;ÿððÈNÖC8°¹0}ÐUƒ¢jË6œèHf£m¸ÔGþ‹Z\sü®Ù28«—4ª–Òë£I¶»å‘ïƒ6ëVoÊÚ¼scä{>"Ë=í_8tœãPN¡¯˜îaò„?    
14/06/08 18:57:28 <<  F
14/06/08 18:57:28 ** Disconnected.
14/06/08 18:57:28 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
14/06/08 18:57:28 ** Disconnected.
14/06/08 18:57:28 ** Disconnected.
14/06/08 18:57:28 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

Anybody give me some advices, please

Comment: Try this link it may be helpful for you 
 


<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TLS to send emails using gmail account.

Do you need to send email from localhost for testing purposes, right? 
If so it seem to me that it is going to be easier to use tools like Papercut or smtp4dev.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue as you and managed to find the answer in the link below
[Sendmail Wamp Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php)

First I did what Rumbel said and then what Yahya Uddin said. After doing what those answers said my mail was sent.

To Sum it up ;

1- Right click on sendmail.exe

2- Properties

3- Compatibility

4- Change the configuration for all users

5- Execute as Windows XP SP 3

6- Execute as adminitrator

7- Execute your server as adminitrator ( In my case right click xampp control panel and run as adminstrator)