# PHP Sendmail Failed in windows xampp

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail, sendmail.exe

I'm trying to sendmail in windows via my gmail account, i've configured my php.ini :

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from=jaisanas2@gmail.com
sendmail_path="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

and sendmail.ini :
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=confidential@gmail.com
auth_password=my-password-confident
force_sender=confidential@gmail.com
```

here is my code :

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
$send = mail('jaisanas2@gmail.com', 'My Subject', $message);
if ($send) {
    echo "send";
}
else {
echo "fail";}
?>
```

also i have change my google security become less secure
i don't have any idea why, anyone help me ?

Comment: You're not escaping backslashes in the `sendmail_path`. That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: it is still fail, i have changed it to sendmail_path="\"C:\\xampp\\sendmail\\sendmail.exe\" -t"

Comment: I wonder if local server can interact to online server. new for me

Comment: i don't know Jean Gkol, but it looks like work for some people  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: Most of the time you can't send mail from the local server, you need to upload the file to a live server.

Comment: Try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php. What windows are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sendmail.exe opens on sending mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514432/sendmail-exe-opens-on-sending-mail)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are using Windows 8 but if you do you must do the following -

1 ) In PHP.ini, make the email part look like this

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = 

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=on
```

2 ) Make sendmail.ini smtp part look like this

```
smtp_server=localhost

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=none

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=user@gmail.com
auth_password=password
```

3 ) Download Stunnel https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html and make the following channges in stunnel.conf. Stunnel is running in the tray, everytime you make changes, right-click the Stunnel icon and Reload the conf file.

```
cert = stunnel.pem
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
key = stunnel.pem
[ssmtp]
accept  = 465
connect = 25
[gmail-smtp]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:25
connect = smtp.gmail.com:465
; To check logs you can enable logging using following lines
debug = 7
```

4 ) Go to your Sendmail folder, righclick sendmail.exe -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Click the Make changes for all users button -> Select Windows XP (Service Pack 3) compatibility and tick Run as admin.

5 ) Always start XAMPP **as admin!!**

This is only needed on Windows 8+ (fex. on Windows 2008 R2 I only needed to properly aim sendmail to gmail and everything was working).

Comment: Select Windows XP (Service Pack 3) is the correct answer for all sendmail problems !! Congratulations

Answer (score 2):

to Windows8

after changeing

1-php.ini

2-sendmail.ini

go to  C:\xampp\sendmail

- 1) Right click sendmail.exe and go to properties.
- 2) click compatibility tab then click change settings for all users.
- 3) set compatibility mode to Windows XP (Service Pack 3)
- 4) click the check box for run this progrma as an administrator

Hope that helps someone else.

its working to my