# how to modify xampp to send mails using php?

Tags: php, email, web, xampp, sendmail.exe

this is my code for sending mail through xampp i have modified the php.ini and sendmail.ini from the xampp . Upon running the php i'm not getting email. Please help me .

php.ini

```
[mail function]

 SMTP =smtp.gmail.com <br>
 smtp_port =587

; For Win32 only.

 ;sendmail_from =email@gmail.com

sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

auth_username=email@gmail.com <br>
auth_password=password <br>
force_sender=email@gmail.com
```

**The php code used for sending email is this**

```
mail("garvit.j742@gmail.com","subject","this is the mail","From:     email@gmail.com");
```

this is my code for php. Tell me the errors ??

Comment: Tell us the errors. Are you getting any? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: yes it is the duplicate of the same question . I followed it but still wasnt able to send the mail

Comment: i checked the error log . <br> "Socket Error # 11001<EOL>Host not found" . This was the error in the error.log

Comment: i have been working for 3 days , and have tried all the possibilities form various websites but still can;t get the mail .i'm using the exact code mentioned above . please rectify the error asap. if you want i can upl the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today too. I found this working solution in SO. Just change sendmail.exe file's compatibility mode to Windows XP SP 3.

1. Right click sendmail.exe and goto properties
2. change compatibility mode to Windows XP SP 3

You can find [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php) here