# sendmail: Error during delivery: Connection Closed Gracefully. mail function php Xampp

Tags: php, email, sendmail.exe

I am new to PHP. I am running XAMPP on Windows 7 PC. I am attempting to create an e-mail contact form using the PHP mail() function. I am uncertain how the configuration of my sendmail.ini and php.ini files affects my code. Does the configuration of the files only affect how the mail function will work on my localhost? or does it affect how the code will run when I upload my content to my web server?

From my php.ini:

```
[mail function]

; For Win32 only.

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port = 995

; For Win32 only.

sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").

sendmail_path = "\"\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters

; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of

; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.

;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the 
filename

;mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers

;mail.log = "\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

From my sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=995

; SMTPS (SSL) support

;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS

;   ssl  = alway use SSL

;   tls  = always use TLS

;   none = never try to use SSL


;smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry

; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided

; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify


;default_domain=mydomain.com


; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)

; uncomment to enable logging


error_logfile=error.log


; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)

; uncomment to enable debugging


debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=myemail@gmail.com

auth_password=mypassword

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 

; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

;pop3_server=

;pop3_username=

;pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address

; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 

; the "From: " header of the message content


force_sender=myemail@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address

; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 

; the "To: " header of the message content


;force_recipient=
```

My code looks like:

```
        $name = $_POST['name1'];

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $message = $_POST['body'];

        $body = $message . '\n My email is ' . $email;



        $header1 = "From: $email \n";

        mail("myemail@gmail.com", $_POST['subject'], $body, $header1);
        header('location:Contact.php');
```

In any case I have been getting two errors: one is that the "connection timed out" and the other is that the "connection closed gracefully.' I googled "connection closed gracefully" and found that I had to run my sendmail.exe file as an administrator and since I am using gmail I had to set up application-specific passwords.

On the post it indicated that I needed to run a server (or IDE) as an administrator as well. Anyone familiar with XAMPP who knows what/where the server/IDE is please respond.

Comment: Aditional, if this doesn't works for someone can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php

Answer (score 2):

Making sure that php and sendmail are run as administrator seems a good idea but this did not solved my problem.

Solution in sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server = smtp.yourisp.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=none
```

*do not use* **smtp_ssl** = **auto** that was what was causing my bug just set it to ssl tls or none according to specification of your server

Answer (score 0):

Try these and I'll be back when I have more time to update this:

1) Never install XAMPP in your Programs folder in Windows. This will cause privilege issues. If you have then re-install it elsewhere.

2) All settings in your sendmail.ini must be configured with what your Apache (Xampp) installation has. The php.ini part you provided is not the full file or the part that has these settings. For example I don;t think your SMTP port is really 995 (I could be wrong).

3) Look at this post: [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

4) SMTP should work now. Your using another mail server (Gmail in this case) to send off your mail. You actually could use your computer as the server too but that is a whole nether issue.