# XAMPP sendmail won't send mail via Gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

This question has been asked repeatedly but none seem to have a solution:

I'm running this test php file:

```
<?php

$to = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test";
$message = "This is a test";
$from = "From: email@gmail.com";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $from)) {
echo 'Email sent successfully!';
} else {
die('Failure');
}
?>
```

after changing the following lines in `php.ini`:

```
[mail function]

sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

as well as these lines in `sendmail.ini`:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587 ;I've tried 465 but gmail doesn't seem to like to connect to SSL
auth_username=email@gmail.com
auth_password=password
```

Mail fails to send and the debug log is as follows:

```
15-02-21 13:35:59 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
15-02-21 13:35:59 ** To: email@gmail.com
15-02-21 13:35:59 ** Subject: Test
15-02-21 13:35:59 ** From: email@gmail.com
15-02-21 13:35:59 ** 
15-02-21 13:35:59 ** This is a test
15-02-21 13:35:59 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
15-02-21 13:36:01 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
15-02-21 13:36:02 ** Connected.
15-02-21 13:36:02 << 220 mx.google.com ESMTP z10sm6176887pas.18 - gsmtp<EOL>
15-02-21 13:36:02 >> EHLO Lenovo-PC<EOL>
15-02-21 13:36:02 << 250-mx.google.com at your service, []<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-CHUNKING<EOL>250 SMTPUTF8<EOL>
15-02-21 13:36:02 ** Authenticating as email@gmail.com
15-02-21 13:36:02 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
15-02-21 13:36:02 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
15-02-21 13:36:02 >> QUIT<EOL>
15-02-21 13:36:02 << bunch of special characters   
15-02-21 13:36:02 ** Disconnected.
15-02-21 13:36:02 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
15-02-21 13:36:02 ** Disconnected.
15-02-21 13:36:02 ** Disconnected.
15-02-21 13:36:02 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aditional, if this doesn't works for someone can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php

Answer (score 2):

Never mind I figured it out... in Windows 8 you are required to change sendmail.exe's compatibility mode (as well as run it in administrator):

1) left click sendmail.exe and go to properties
2) click compatibility tab then click change settings for all users
3) set compatibility mode to Windows XP (Service Pack 3)
4) click the check box for run this progrma as an administrator

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: OH MY GOH! FINALLY!  You sir. you have put an end to my two day hunt for an answer. Thank you so much. I've reconfigured my php.ini and sendmail.ini too many times only to find out that this was the answer. thank you thank you thank you for putting me out of my misery.