# wamp sendmail failed to send email through smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: php, email, gmail, wamp, sendmail

```
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
mail('myemail@yahoo.com', 'My Subject', $message);
```

php.ini =>

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
;SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25
;smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = you@yourdomain
sendmail_from = ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = 
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

sendmail.ini =>

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
;smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com
;smtp_server=localhost
; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587
;smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

;smtp_ssl=auto
smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=localhost

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
auth_password=[mypassword]

;auth_username=
;auth_password=

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

It is not sending email.
I don't want to use external library like PHPmailer, swiftmailer,hmailserver etc.

Has anyone sent email on windows with php mail?
What should i do?

Edit:
The following configuration works: (sendmail is put in C:)

php.ini =>

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587        
sendmail_from = ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\sendmail\sendmail.exe"
```

sendmail.ini =>

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto

error_logfile=error.log    
auth_username=ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
auth_password=[mypassword]    
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=
```

Comment: Have you activated `extension=php_openssl.dll` in the `php.ini` file

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i have checked php_openssl from wamp->php->php-extension

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running

Comment: This looks like a good [tutorial on how to](http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, wampserver-2.1

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8

Comment: You should really think about upgrading to WAMPServer3. 2.1 is ancient

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I have updated wamp to 2.5.

Comment: It's working after changing the compatibility mode of sendmail.exe from properties. For windows 7 or above, you have to change the compatibility mode of sendmail.exe to "Windows xp service pack 3" from properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php , see "issues running on windows 8+" here in http://glob.com.au/sendmail/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure these two lines in php.ini are uncommented:

```
;SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
;smtp_port = 587 (or 465)
```

Then change `smtp_ssl=auto` to `smtp_ssl=tls` (as RiggsFolly said make sure `extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled).

Furthermore if you are using Windows 8 have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21380421/2568469) thread or install [this](https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html) proxy.

Edit: (edited by shibly)

The following configuration works.

php.ini=>

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587        
sendmail_from = ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\sendmail\sendmail.exe"
```

sendmail.ini=>

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto

error_logfile=error.log    
auth_username=ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
auth_password=[mypassword]    
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=ssmtpmailtesting@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=
```

Comment: `smtp_ssl=auto` works

Comment: It's working after changing the compatibility mode of sendmail.exe from properties. For windows 7 or above, you have to change the compatibility mode of sendmail.exe to "Windows xp service pack 3" from properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php , see "issues running on windows 8+" here in http://glob.com.au/sendmail/

Comment: Use the latest [sendmail for Windows](https://github.com/sendmail-tls1-2/main) and follow the basic installation instructions, make sure to remove the `smtp` configuration from your `php.ini` file because that isn't really required if you already handle those values in your `sendmail.ini` file. Also I was only able to get it to work if I use `sendmail_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\sendmail\sendmail.exe"` without the `-t` parameter. If anyone is curious, I was using IIS on Windows 10.