# What are the PHPMailer requirement for sending mail and receiving mail in IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7, phpmailer, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running a Windows 2008r2 server with PHP and IIS 7.0 installed, and I want to add phpmailer to my IIS 7, but I'm not sure what roles or features I need installed

From my understanding to run phpmailer I just have to unzip the phpmailer folder and drop all the files in the project file where I have a website and then edit some commands.

But then if I have to send an email. Do I need to have the SMTP feature installed on my IIS 7? Or does PHP send it without SMTP installed? Also do I need any other features installed to make sure it works?

I'm asking because I havent been able to install SMTP successful or run phpmailer successfully, so I would like to know all the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have some form of mail server installed and preferably [configured in php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php). That doesn't mean it has to run on your Windows server, it just has to be running somewhere and accessible to said server. So you could have a Linux box running sendmail and tell your Windows PHP to use that to send mail through.

Comment: What other options do I have besides ISS and Linuxbox? Are there any other preferred mail servers to use with php mailer that are easy to configure?

Comment: PHPMailer doesn't care what mail server you use, so long as it can talk SMTP to it. As far as I'm aware, Windows Server includes a mail server, though you may need to enable and configure it, so refer to your docs on that.

Comment: Windows Server (except Small Business) does not come with a mail server. Microsoft's only email product is Exchange. But @Synchro is right, any SMTP server will do. There is a [sendmail for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php) but it's not a native Windows application (hence why I would suggest a Linux box)

Comment: OK, I thought there was some less fully-featured MS product than Exchange, but apparently not. There is https://www.hmailserver.com which looks like it should do the trick, or you can use an external service like smtp.com, sendgrid etc.