# Mail sent but not received, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I have configured the following settings

```
 $config = Array(

        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'send-mail@gmail.com', // change it to yours
        'smtp_pass' => 'xyz', // change it to yours
        'smtp_timeout'=>20,
        'mailtype' => 'text',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
       );

$this->load->library('email',$config);
//$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('sender-mail@gmail.com', 'Garima');
$this->email->to('receiver-mail@gmail.com');

// mail message here
```

I get the following message:

> Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol:
>   mail
>
> From: "Garima" send-mail@gmail.com
>
> Return-Path: send-mail@gmail.com
>
> Reply-To: "send-mail@gmail.com"
>
> X-Sender: send-mail@gmail.com
>
> X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
>
> X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>
> Message-ID: <@gmail.com>
>
> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Firstly,If i have defined the protocol as smtp, why does it show the protocol as mail.

Secondly, There is no "to" field in the message shown. Why is it so? what changes do i have to make?

Comment: What type of local host you using to test on? xammp wamp etc

Comment: Another thing is make some times codeigniter will not send unless send email settings are configured in xampp settings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to initialize the email config setting in your code

```
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

So your code would be

```
 $this->load->library('email');
        $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'send-mail@gmail.com', // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => 'xyz', // change it to yours
                'smtp_timeout'=>20,
                'mailtype' => 'text',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
               );

         $this->email->initialize($config);// add this line

        //$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('sender-mail@gmail.com', 'Garima');
        $this->email->to('receiver-mail@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  
        $this->email->send();
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: Thankyou. It took me out of the problem mentioned above but now it shows a lot of errors "fsockopen(): Unable to connect" Unable to send data . @Saty

Comment: Sounds good you out of your problem!!. Now what error you got please paste your error

Comment: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto

 fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Unknown error)

fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Such errors @Saty

Comment: little change in code `$this->load->library('email');` remove `$config` from this line

Comment: Change `'smtp_port' => 465`, to `'smtp_port' => 587`, and check

Comment: Greetings! It throws an error when I try to initialize it this way. `fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to load library first

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

then config these settings [Can Refer here too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622996/4595675)

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',//your E-mail
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',//Your password
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$result = $this->email->send();
```

Send mail using **localhost**

1. If you are using **XAMPP** do this settings [Stack Answer for Send mail
   with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/4595675)
2. If you are sending mail with **wamp** [Stack Answer for Send mail with
   WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21380421/4595675)

To read more about CI E-mail [CI E-Mail Library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)