# Unable send mail from localhost, other than gmail id using wamp

Tags: php, email

I want to send email from myid@mysite.com. I have configured my wamp as per [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost) below above code works fine to send using gmail account but not using other domain account e.g. Want to send from myid@mysite.com.

Please guide me.

In php.ini I have made following changes

```
<?php
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"D:\wampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
?>
```

In sendmail.ini I have changed code to

```
<?php

    [sendmail]

    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port=587
    error_logfile=error.log
    debug_logfile=debug.log
    auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
    auth_password=my-gmail-password
    force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com

    ?>
```

Comment: Try that fix 'Sendmail has to be run as an administrator': http://stackoverflow.com/a/21380421/2851845

Comment: Still I'm not able to send mail.

Comment: Hey I got the solution, I made changes in php.ini at : sendmail_path="D:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"... And I got mail.

Comment: I used http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php link

Comment: Above code works fine for sending mail from any email id from localhost in wamp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sendmail.exe, I suggest you use the library PHPMailer.

You have an example here:
[Basic Example using Gmail](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail)

Comment: I have also tried for above code but it's giiving me error as : Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in D:\wamp\www\....\class.phpmailer.php on line 1291

Comment: Have you download the library before ?
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/master/class.phpmailer.php

Comment: yes, I've downloaded too. That's why I tried above code, which is not showing error but not sending mail too.. I am using wamp on win 7 starter.

Comment: Also I want to send email to any type of email id including gmail.