# Sendmail : Connection closed gracefully

Tags: php, email

I am using wamp server on Windows with the [sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) program. I am trying to send an e-mail from my personal computer with my business email.

I configured the sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=localhost
smtp_port=1055
default_domain=company.something
auth_username=mymail@company.something
auth_password= *****
```

I also changed the php.ini

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 1055
sendmail_path = "path\to\sendmail.exe"
```

And after reading others [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php) I used this trick

```
1º Right click on sendmail.exe    
2º Properties    
3º Compatibility    
4º Change the configuration for all users    
5º Execute as Windows XP SP 3    
6º Execute as adminitrator
```

But still got the `"Connection Closed Gracefully."` error.
I am sure that my SMTP is correct because I use the same with Thunderbird and it run everyday since a year ago without any problem.

I am also sure that my configuration is well working because I tried to change the parameters to use a gmail account and **it is working**.

I just want to know, what this error mean ?

Comment: Aditional, if this doesn't works for someone can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php