# Gmail error when sending local email via Xampp (must issue a STARTTLS command)

Tags: php, email, xampp, gmail, sendmail.exe

I installed the XAMPP server and now I'm trying to send my local email via the gmail server. To do so, I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php) and changed my php.ini and sendmail.ini as follows:

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = xxx.xxx@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=local

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=xxx.xxx@gmail.com
auth_password=xxx

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines

;pop3_server=
;pop3_username=
;pop3_password=

; to force the sender to always be the following email address, uncomment and
; populate with a valid email address.  this will only affect the "MAIL FROM"
; command, it won't modify the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=xxx.xxx@gmail.com

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

;hostname=localhost
```

With those settings, I'll get the following error back from the gmail server:

```
16/01/18 20:47:28 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
16/01/18 20:47:28 ** Connected.
16/01/18 20:47:28 << 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w80sm17190895wme.17 - gsmtp<EOL>
16/01/18 20:47:28 >> EHLO SamClauw<EOL>
16/01/18 20:47:28 << 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [213.118.20.101]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-CHUNKING<EOL>250 SMTPUTF8<EOL>
16/01/18 20:47:28 ** Authenticating as xxx.xxx@gmail.com
16/01/18 20:47:28 >> MAIL FROM: <xxx.xxx@gmail.com><EOL>
16/01/18 20:47:28 << 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. w80sm17190895wme.17 - gsmtp<EOL>
16/01/18 20:47:28 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
16/01/18 20:47:28 ** Disconnected.
16/01/18 20:47:28 ** Disconnected.
16/01/18 20:47:28 ** Must issue a STARTTLS command first. w80sm17190895wme.17 - gsmtp<EOL>
```

As you can see: I've made a connection but after that, there's an issue with a STARTTLS command or something.

I Googled and I tried a lot:

- administrator rights for XAMPP
- smtp port 25 and 465
- ssl://smtp.gmail.com instead of smtp.gmail.com
- lower security on my gmail account
- ...

But none of this is helping. Is there somebody who had the same problem and could fix this? What setting should I change so it could finally work?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I've tried the same list of things to get this working and I still can't send email.  Was hoping this post had the answers, but you've tried everything I did even lower security on my gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once so I tried to connect via TLS and that worked.
this is my output from my mailer:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

I am using phpmailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/), so you should try to connect to host: tls://smtp.gmail.com:587.

Comment: When I change the php.ini value for SMTP to "tls://smtp.gmail.com" and the sendmail.php value for smtp_server to "tls://smtp.gmail.com",
I've got the following error in my debug log: Connecting to tls:25 - 16/01/20 19:21:50 ** Disconnected. - 16/01/20 19:21:50 ** Disconnected. - 16/01/20 19:21:50 ** Disconnected. - 16/01/20 19:21:50 ** Socket Error # 11004<EOL>. It seems it doesn't work in my case. Is PHPMailer not the one that XAMPP uses to send local email?

Comment: You have to use port 587 and not port 25
try: tls://smtp.gmail.com:587

Answer (score 0):

set **smtp_ssl** to auto in sendmail.ini

```
; SMTPS (SSL) support
; auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
; ssl  = alway use SSL
; tls  = always use TLS
; none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto
```