# cant get contact form to send emails in wordpress for gmail account from localhost

Tags: wordpress, email

In word press I have installed the plugin and I have a contact form on a webpage (localhost) on wamp64.
I enter data into the form and submit but I receive no email but no error.
I then read I needed to download the smpt plugin and I am using a gmail account.
I set this up but again the form doesn't send me an email.

```
I also followed these settings for gmail and it still didn't work where my host was smtp.gmail.com
    http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-receive-wordpress-emails-from-localhost/

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-create-a-contact-form-in-wordpress/

On the test email from the smpt plugin I see the error but I don't know what settings I need to use to make this work from a gmail account.

    The SMTP debugging output is shown below:

 Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php) helps.

Comment: I am using wordpress plugins and this post doesnt address that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below plugin which is working only after provide proper credential from admin.

[WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/screenshots/)

Comment: please remove your answer as it isnt an answer

Comment: then you have to switch selection and try from test mail ...check your credential as well..it should work.

Comment: this is from the test mail. The SMTP debugging output is shown below:

 Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: use  No encryption at  Encryption option. uncheck SSL

Comment: This simply doesnt work with wordpress. I have tried all combinations for settings with TLS and without.. using a MVC framework I can email easy from the same gmail account on the same computer

Comment: i am using php 5.6 which I see many people are having problems with send email

Comment: i am using PHP 5.6 as well and having no problem with this plugin since last 3 month.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin is faulty .
A common solution is to edit the plugin which is really not a great way to get it to work.

for emails to work need to add in this code before line 149 on file wp_email_smtp

```
                $phpmailer = apply_filters('wp_mail_smtp_custom_options', $phpmailer);
                $phpmailer->SMTPOptions = array(
                    'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                    )
                    );
```