# Cannot get sendmail to work with Swiftmailer Bundle on Windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, sendmail, swiftmailer

I have the following setup/parameters:

- PHP 7.1.26
- Windows 10 x64 Professional
- symfony/swiftmailer-bundle 3.5.2
- symfony/console 4.1.11

I want to configure the swiftmailer-bundle to use the [fake `sendmail`](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/), which is installed at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\sendmail
```

While I have already configured the `sendmail_path` in PHP, the swiftmailer-bundle does not actually use this PHP variable at all. Instead it defaults the path to the sendmail executable to

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs
```

However, since version 3.0.4, the path (i.e. complete command) should be configurable: https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/pull/185

I put

```
swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        default:
            transport: sendmail
            command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t'
```

into my `app/config/config.yml` and rebuilt the cache. However, when I want to send a test email via

```
swiftmailer:email:send
```

it still uses the default command - which of course fails with

```
[Swift_TransportException]
Process could not be started [The system cannot find the specified path.]
```

I am not sure what else I could try. I would really like to use the fake sendmail setup in my local environment, because sendmail can be configured to force send any email to a specific address (my address) for testing and always use a specific SMTP.

This is the output of `debug:config swiftmailer`:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default
    mailers:
        default:
            transport: sendmail
            host: 127.0.0.1
            username: null
            password: null
            port: 25
            encryption: null
            command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t'
            url: null
            timeout: 30
            source_ip: null
            local_domain: null
            auth_mode: null
            delivery_addresses: {  }
            logging: false
            delivery_whitelist: {  }
```

Comment: did you tried with double slashes: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sendmail\\sendmail.exe -t' and not shure about spaces :)

Comment: also in the docs https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/ there is a link to stack:) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337859/sendmail-wamp-php

Comment: @myxaxa: no - but I did debug within the code of Swiftmailer and the config simply did not arrive at the `Swift_SendmailTransport` class. It still uses the default `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs`.

Comment: @myxaxa: the Stackoverflow link only concerns the PHP configuration. The Swiftmailer Bundle does not use the PHP configuration.

Comment: sorry for a late response. it's weird. are you sure that there is no other config's for swiftmailer in your project? please run this command: php bin/console debug:config swiftmailer and show the output https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html

Comment: Yes, I am sure there are no other configs. I have added the output of `debug:config swiftmailer` to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

*update* an open issue found on github: https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/issues/244

so it was a hard way. but try this one in your's swiftmailer.yaml:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default
    mailers:
        default:
            transport: sendmail
            command: '%env(SENDMAIL_COMMAND)%'
            timeout: 20
```

and add a new env-variable in your .env file:

```
SENDMAIL_COMMAND='C:\Program Files (x86)\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t'
```

this was found during debuging SwiftmailerExtension.php file on line 96 you can find and if statement witch can help to understand how it works

Comment: Hm, seems weird. Why not directly put the command path into `swiftmailer.mailers.default.command`? What difference does it make when doing it via an environment variable?

Comment: I don't know - just look here - https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/SwiftmailerExtension.php#L89 :)

Comment: only in case of env variable you'll pass the if block and use the factory to create an instance of transport and only then method setCommand of the transport is called

Comment: I've updated the post - found an open issue on github about all this stuff - https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/issues/244 :) thanks @fritzmg for this quiz!