# Using phpmailer with gmail why isnt it working

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

i am using phpmailer to submit a form and send it to my email but it wont work and im out of ideas why it wont work. Would you guys take a look at it for me and figure out why its not working? Its giving me an error that says sorry could not send at this time, which is the error that i made. Any ideas why its not working?

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'libs/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'])) {
    $fields = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
    'message' => $_POST['message']
    ];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)) {
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
    }
}

if(empty($errors)) {

    $m = new PHPMailer;

    $m->isSMTP();
    $m->SMTPAuth = true;

    $m->HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $m->Username = 'contactdocketsolution@gmail.com';
    $m->Password = 'not showing password but it is valid';
    $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $m->Port = 465;

    $m->isHTML();

    $m->Subject = '' . $fields['subject'] . 'Docket-Solutions COntact Form';
    $m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p>';

    $m->FromName = 'Docket-Solutions Customer';

    $m->AddAddress('support@docket-solutions.com', 'Bob');

    if($m->send()) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        die();
    }else{
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.';
    }


}

} else {
$errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;
header('Location: contact.php');




?>
```

Comment: Have you enabled [Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) on your GMail accont?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), base your code on [an up to date example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), read any of the hundreds of duplicates of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer with GMail: SMTP Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867017/phpmailer-with-gmail-smtp-error)