# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php

I've change also the security of gmail to on and also the openssl from php.ini.

It gives me the same error every time.

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

```
<?php

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'mail/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'mail/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'mail/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'test';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Janson');
    $mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
   // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    //$mail->MsgHTML($Message);

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer with GMail: SMTP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867017/phpmailer-with-gmail-smtp-error)

Comment: Can you kindly explain in more detail pls? thanks